# LD option for deterministic loading of program and shared objects?

Tags: linux, arm, ld

I'm working on an unusual problem on a BeagleBone Black. The "unusual" part is stepping under the debug causes a `SIGILL` that was not formerly present.

Addresses are moving around between runs due to PIC and PIE. I want to force LD to perform a deterministic load. The idea is to do something like:

```
LD_BASE_ADDRESS=0x1000 ./test.exe
```

Or maybe:

```
LD_ADDRESS_SEED=0x0000 ./test.exe
```

And then get reproducible results like when a random number generator is seeded with the same seed.

I checked the [`ld.so(8)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html) man page, but I don't see the option. `LD_USE_LOAD_BIAS` looks close but its not clear to me if it provides the deterministic behavior.

How do I tell LD to deterministically load the programs and all its shared objects?

Answer (score 2):

This isn’t controlled by the linker, it’s controlled by the kernel. You can disable ASLR using [`randomize_va_space`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/plain/Documentation/sysctl/kernel.txt):

```
echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space
```

To re-enable it:

```
echo 2 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space
```

You can also disable it for a single process using `setarch` to apply the appropriate personality:

```
setarch $(uname -m) -R command
```

will run `command` without ASLR.

Comment: Thanks again Stephen. It turned out to be a moot point. I was witnessing a GDB/Kernel bug: [Program OK outside debugger, SIGILL under debugger when stepping?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45649778/608639) All the debugging in the world would not have helped the issue.